# Como inserir a média de uma tabela em outra tabela?

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, procedure

Criei este banco:

```
create table aluno(
codaluno int primary key,
nome varchar(30),
datanasc date);

create table curso(
codcurso int primary key,
descricao_c varchar(200));

create table disciplina(
coddisc int primary key,
descricao_d varchar(200),
creditos int,
cod_curso int,
constraint fk_codcurso foreign key (cod_curso) references curso (codcurso));

create table matricula(
cod_aluno int,
cod_disc int,
data date,
nota1 number(3,1),
nota2 number(3,1),
nota3 number(3,1),
constraint fk_codaluno foreign key (cod_aluno) references aluno (codaluno),
constraint fk_coddisc foreign key (cod_disc) references disciplina (coddisc));

create table historico(
semestre int,
nota_final number(3,1),
cod_alun int,
cod_dis int,
constraint fk_codal foreign key (cod_alun) references aluno (codaluno),
constraint fk_coddi foreign key (cod_dis) references disciplina (coddisc));

insert into aluno values (01, 'John', to_date('07/04/1998', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
insert into aluno values (02, 'Anna', to_date('03/07/2000', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
insert into aluno values (03, 'Marcio', to_date('05/12/1995', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));

insert into curso values (01, 'Computação');
insert into curso values (02, 'Direito');

insert into disciplina values (01, 'Algoritmos 1', 4, 1);
insert into disciplina values (02, 'Código Penal', 4, 2);

insert into matricula values (01, 01, to_date('08/01/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 9.3, 10.0, 8.8);
insert into matricula values (02, 01, to_date('07/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 8.7, 7.5, 10.0);
insert into matricula values (03, 01, to_date('09/01/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 10.0, 10.0, 9.5);

insert into historico values (01, 0.0, 01, 01);
insert into historico values (01, 0.0, 02, 01);
insert into historico values (01, 0.0, 03, 01);
```

Eu gostaria de saber como fazer para retirar a média das 3 notas de um aluno e inserir este valor dentro da nota final que está na tabela histórico. Obviamente terei que dar update nela e eu tentei fazer isso através de um procedure:

```
create or replace procedure UPDATEhistorico (   
p_nota_final in historico.nota_final%TYPE)  
is  
begin  
update historico set AVG(nota_final)=p_notafinal where aluno.codaluno = matricula.cod_aluno
and disciplina.coddisc = matricula.cod_disc
and curso.codcurso = disciplina.cod_curso;  
end;
```

Não faz sentido nenhum o que eu tentei fazer, por isso vim pedir auxílio.

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer através de um *update* da seguinte forma:

```
Update historico set
  nota_final =  (Select (NVL(m.nota1,0)+NVL(m.nota2,0)+NVL(m.nota3,0))/3 from matricula m
                  where m.cod_aluno = historico.cod_alun
                    and m.cod_disc = historico.cod_dis
                    and historico.semestre = 1)
```

Após a execução do comando, os dados do seu exemplo ficaram assim:
**Consulta 1**:

```
Select * from historico
```

**Resultado**:

| SEMESTRE | NOTA_FINAL | COD_ALUN | COD_DIS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9.4 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 8.7 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 9.8 | 3 | 1 |

Exemplo disponível em http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7407/1.

Visto que no seu exemplo existem os campos para cada nota, utilizei a soma e divisão para gerar a média. Correlacionei as tabelas histórico e matricula para gerar a média e atualizar o campo `nota_final` da tabela `historico`.
Utilizado `NVL` para prever valores nulos e considerá-los como zero.
O semestre está informado no update.

### Visão Profissional:

Profissionalmente, o `historico` deveria ser atualizado via [Trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm) que automatizaria essa atualização toda vez que uma nota em matrícula fosse atualizada. Visto que se uma nota em matrícula for atualizada e o comando de atualização do `historico` não for executado, você terá dados inconsistentes na sua base da dados.
Outro ponto a analisar é se realmente é necessário gerar esse histórico ou se a criação de uma *view* não forneceria a informação que precisa.
São pontos a analisar conforme sua regra de negócio.

Comment: Resposta foi negativada, então resolvi melhorá-la. Melhorei o comando `update` incluindo `and historico.semestre = 1` no comando, usei o `NVL` e expliquei o motivo, incluí uma visão profissional para alertar sobre pontos de atenção e sugerir o uso de `Trigger` se necessário.  Caso alguém possa informar no que mais a resposta pode ser melhorada, agradeço o tempo dispensado a fazer tal comentário e buscarei aplicá-lo nesta resposta e nas futuras.

Comment: Segunda ou terceira resposta sua que vejo sendo negativada sem um motivo que eu compreenda. Deixando claro que é minha opinião pessoal, mas e passei recentemente por uma situação similar eu estava sendo sistematicamente negativado por sem motivação pessoal e sem critério técnico. Se achar que seja o caso de votação sistemática sinalize as publicações que  tenha suspeita pedindo por auditoria. No meu caso resolveu e consegui reverter a votação.